# how to add emmet in vs code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, emmet

I want to use emmet on VS Code for React and they say emmet is default on vs code, I don't need to add an emmet extension. I check on setting there is emmet section. but, Is it only default to HTML and CSS?

[image: My VS Code Setting]

Please Help me to add it.

I check the internet slightly but every one said, to go to user setting>extension>emmet> under Then select Extensions >  Emmet Include: Languages and select the Edit in settings.JSON link directly underneath it.
but in my vs, I don't have this setting.JSON under the Emmet Include: Language. i just have Item value and ADD Item beneath it. like tin the pic.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to settings
2. search Emmet include languages
3. click on Add item
4. put "javascript" as the key and "javascriptreact" as the value
5. click ok

Answer (score 0):

You can click "Add Item", and then input the values as shown in the pic, this new version is much more simple.
[Emmet setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKtbT.png)

Comment: This seems to be correct, but can you add a bit more explanation.